# Postman How to use the value from response and use it in request afterword

Tags: collections, postman, chaining

Is there a simple way in Postman to:

- **request a token** then use this token as **Authorization value in the header of next request**.

Or

- When created a new entry can we to use the **newly created entry_id** to for further actions e.g. `Update/Delete`

I want the chaining requests of a collection or a folder without stop and edit every request body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say I want to create a new obj called 'qif' then get its id, and then update it.

1. In Postman open the first request - **Test tab** enter:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("new_create_qif_id", jsonData.id);
```

[image]

2. after sending the request you will get the environment valuable `new_create_qif_id` ready.

[image]

3. use `{{new_create_qif_id}}` in request body or URL, it will be updated every time we run the collection or folder

[image]

Requesting token is just the same.

Comment: When I use my id in body the value is not obtained, just gets string of {{myVariable}}